# How to run a Spring portlet

Tags: java, spring, jboss, portlet

I am new to Spring portlet i am unable to run a sample spring portlet project.. I am trying to run the project from eclipse as run on server on jboss server. My questions are 1. How can we run a portlet project. Do i need some kind of portlet container(I have no idea of this container i just know few names like liferay etc)?? I cant find a full documented example any where.. In Spring mvc based on the request mapping i can call that purticular Controller class but in Spring mvc portlet how can we call this controllers( or Portlets). Is it possible to call a portlet directly by an url?? The sample project is deployed without any error but i cant find a way by which i can call or trigger a portlet. Any help would be much appriciated.
thx
nkovi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will need to deploy to a portlet container like Liferay etc, or uPortal. Once you have the portlet container up and running, things should hopefully become more obvious.

Regarding your other questions, I strongly suggest you read some documentation - the [Spring portlet docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/portlet.html) are not too bad although they are a little behind on annotations.